# WhoId, OwnerId and WhatId CSV Headers?

Tags: relationships, bulk-api, ownership, owner, whatid

**Polymorphic & Relationship Fields** 
I'm trying to insert a task via Bulk API and providing the below csv headers, but getting Malformed_ID error.

```
Owner:User.FederationIdentifier 
Contact:Who.Id 
Case:What.CaseNumber
```

What should be the correct headers for Owner, WhoId and WhatId if I want to use the relationship fields ?

Answer (score 3):

So -- the values in the rows be used for insert

- Task.WhatId should be the `Case.Id` (i.e. starts with `500...`)
- Task.WhoId should be a `Contact.Id` (i.e. starts with `003...`)
- Task.OwnerId should be some `User.Id` (i.e. starts with `005...`)

What you are trying to do is [upsert a task using external Ids](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upsert.htm) to identify the parent (`CaseNumber` for the `Whatid`). `caseNumber` is not an external Id field.

Same issue with `FederationId` for the `OwnerId`. If you look at the metadata for that field, it is not marked as an ExternalId

Comment: I want to use the User's Federation Id for updating the owner, similarly I want to use the CaseNumber on the case instead of caseId.